# Is "than did" correct in the following sentence, and if so, why?

Tags: comparisons

"A study finds older people who ate ... leafy greens had a slower rate of decline ... **than did** people who rarely ate vegetables."

Comment: Why do you think it would not be correct? Can you elaborate on your research so far?

Comment: You don't actually need the *did*. But it doesn't make it wrong.

Comment: I'm helping an ESL student/friend with the question. I believe the usage is correct, but I haven't found a simple rule to explain why "did" was used. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Than* is one of the contexts which allow inversion in a non-interrogative sentence. Most of the other contexts are heavy sentence-adverbs (or adverbial phrases); for example: "In vain did he ... " "Not for nothing was it ... "; "Scarcely had I ... "

Comment: Generally, subject-auxiliary inversion outside questions requires negation. _Than_ is limited to marking the baseline clause in comparative constructions. Comparatives can trigger NPIs, like _smarter than they ever thought_. Here the negation licenses subj-aux inversion, like _in vain_ and _scarcely_ do.